# Change the size of the keyboard view

Tags: android, view, keyboard

Is it possible to change the size of a keyboard view?  The default setting of a keyboard will span across the screen, but is it possible to resize a keyboard? (e.g. make the keyboard only take half of the screen?)

Answer (score 0):

No, not unless you create a custom keyboard and ask users to install it as well.